# Does python sqlite3 deallocate a memory only database in interactive mode?

Tags: python, memory, sqlite

I was looking at the Python unit tests for sqlite3 today and I noticed something awesome

`sqlite.connect(":memory:")`

This is a really cool idea that makes unit tests much easier to write. But then I started wondering, does sqlite3 always dealloacte memory used? Is sqlite3 smart enough to deallocate in interactive mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

Before:

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
ryan     27162  0.4  0.2  29492  5348 pts/7    S+   15:17   0:00 python
```

After inserting 500000 rows:

```
ryan     27162 14.3  0.7  45436 15064 pts/7    S+   15:17   0:13 python
```

After `db.close()`

```
ryan     27162 11.9  0.4  38620  8368 pts/7    S+   15:17   0:13 python
```

However, after inserting 500000 rows and then doing `db.execute("drop table test")`, memory usage was not freed again. Creating a new test db and inserting rows again did not cause additional memory allocations, so it looks like the memory just wasn't returned to the OS.

Answer (score 1):

**OSX Activity monitor was not reporting correct memory usage. use htop to see correct usage statistics.**

First I started the interpreter in interactive mode

`python -i`

Then in the interpreter I wrote

```
import sqlite3 as sqlite
db = sqlite.connect(":memory:")
db.execute("create table test(id integer primary key, test_text text)")
for i in range(50000000):
    db.execute("insert into test(test_text) values (?)", ("test",))
```

The first screen shot is the memory usage while interactive python is running. The memory usage is ~488mb.

[image]

Small Note, OSX activity monitor identifies the python interpreter as "Terminal" probably because it doesn't check for children's memory usage (doesn't look at forks).

[image]

This second screenshot is after exit() is called in the interpreter. The memory usage is still at ~488mb In short, the memory isn't deallocated on interpreter exit.

**Update:**
Original test was 3.4. Just confirmed with 2.7.

**Update2:**
Attempted the test again with htop.
[image]

[image]

Apparently the lesson isn't that python.sqlite3 doesn't deallocate in interactive mode, it's that you shouldn't use OSX activity monitor to test memory usage.

Nothing to see here, move along.

Comment: You should check with htop or something that shows child processes. I believe this might be a bug in the Monitor or something, as the child process (and its memory consumption) should have vanished.

Comment: This is the correct answer it turns out. htop is showing the memory as not in use.